# Android: где и как правильно держать сокет соединение?

Tags: android, java, сокет

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, где и как правильно создавать и держать соединение сокета? Использую библиотеку [`Autobahn WS`](http://autobahn.ws/android/). В примерах у них сокет создается в активити, но при повороте экрана тогда происходит переподключение сокета. Попробовал вынести его в отдельный класс, но мне нужно иметь хоть какой-нибудь контекст и доступ к контент провидерам, а этого нет. Как быть? Куда его запихнуть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> нужно иметь хоть какой-нибудь контекст и доступ к контент провидерам
>
> Куда его запихнуть?

В сервис.